# Angular $resource static model method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

Say I have an AngularJS `$resource` defined like this:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])
  .factory('PanelUser', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/panel/users/:userId', {
      userId: '@_id'
    }, {
      invite: {
        method: 'POST'
      }
    });
  }]);
```

Now say I instantiate a user `var user = new PanelUser();` How can I call `user.hasAuthorization()` to do some checks on the client. I don't need to make requests to the server, but I need to be able to do it on each user as an instance method.

Comment: since your `hasAuthorization` method has a url it's not clear what you mean by not needing to make calls to server. Overall issue is a bit vague

Comment: @charlietfl I'm refactoring that to be handled on the client side because it will be simpler and require no requests, but it should be an instance method. I removed the code to avoid confusion.

Comment: might want to take a look at Restangular, it's more robust than $resource and easier to extend